# Is there a way to type hint a pandas object's index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, protocols, typing

I'd like to type hint that a pandas dataframe must have a datetimeindex. I was hoping there might be some way to do this with protocols but looks like no. Something in the spirit of this:

```
class TSFrame(Protocol):
    index: pd.DatetimeIndex

def test(df: TSFrame):
    # Do stuff with df.index.methods_supported_by_dtidx_only
    pass

nontsdf = pd.DataFrame()
tsdf = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02")))
test(nontsdf)  # goal is for my interpreter to complain here
test(tsdf)  # and not complain here
```

My interpreter instead complains in both cases. Confusingly, if I create an analogous test on a generic class but where the type hint is int, it complains in neither case.

```
class IntWanted(Protocol):
    var: int

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, var: Any) -> None:
        self.var = var

def foo(a: IntWanted) -> int:
    return a.var

good = TestClass(1)
bad = TestClass("x")
foo(good)
foo(bad)
```

Other ways I can think of to treat these timeseries dataframes:

1. Subclass dataframe and add validation that the index is a datetimeindex. Convert every df I have into an instance of this class and type hint that class everywhere. Would that solve the problem of mypy knowing its index has the attributes of a dtidx though? I think not. E.g.

```py
class TSFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        assert isinstance(self.index, pd.DatetimeIndex)
```

2. Make an entirely new object that has a df as one attribute, defined an index that is a datetimeindex created from the input df's index so it's known by mypy what type that index has. This feels heavy.

```py
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class TSFrame:
    df: pd.DataFrame

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        assert isinstance(self.index, pd.DatetimeIndex)

    @property
    def index(self) -> pd.DatetimeIndex:
        return pd.DatetimeIndex(self.df.index)
```

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandera`](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) (and [`pandas-stub`](https://github.com/VirtusLab/pandas-stubs)) to do pretty much whatever you want.

1. `pip install pandera[mypy]`
2. Create a `mypy.ini` file with:

```
[mypy]
plugins = pandera.mypy
```

`demo.py`

```
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandera.typing import Index, DataFrame, Series

class TSFrame(pa.DataFrameModel):
    idx: Index[pa.Timestamp] = pa.Field(check_name=False)

@pa.check_types  # at runtime
def test(df: DataFrame[TSFrame]):  # at compile time
    pass

nontsdf = pd.DataFrame()
tsdf = DataFrame[TSFrame](index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02")))
test(nontsdf)
test(tsdf)
```

Usage:

```
[...]$ mypy demo.py
demo1.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "test" has incompatible type "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame"; expected "pandera.typing.pandas.DataFrame[TSFrame]"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

[...]$ python demo.py
...
pandera.errors.SchemaError: error in check_types decorator of function 'test': expected series 'None' to have type datetime64[ns], got int64
```

More information:

- [Integration with MyPy](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mypy_integration.html)
- [DataFrame Models](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_models.html)
- [Decorate Functions and Coroutines](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/decorators.html?highlight=assert#decorate-functions-and-coroutines)

Comment: This is a good answer so happy to award you the bounty. Still also interested in solutions that only use native python + pandas, though. Looks like pandera gets 1-2 commits a month which is a bit low to rely on for a production system.

Comment: To check at the runtime level, you can actually subclass DataFrame but it's [a long job](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html)
(The bounty expired before you accepted my answer so it wasn't awarded but that's okay.)

Comment: I hope it will get awarded based on this: https://stackoverflowteams.help/en/articles/4396994-bounties - 
"If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)."